# Installing Paclets in Mathematica online?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, paclets

Is there a way to install custom packages in Mathematica online?

IE, following instructions to install Carl Woll's https://github.com/carlwoll/TensorSimplify, I get "The PacletManager application is running in read-only mode; paclets cannot be installed or uninstalled"

On a higher level, it seems like a useful feature to support. Here's an example of how it works in Google Colab -- you can "pip install" or "apt-get" arbitrary binaries which stick around on kernel restart. If your session expires, the disk is wiped, but you can just rerun the installation cells -- https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Ggc5zZpDHF0aOYr_QZZT63ko1thmJZuY

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Upload the file `TensorSimplify.m` to `Base/Applications` in your WolframCloud.  Then `` <<TensorSimplify` `` loads the package.